# What method to catch context menu item selected in custom view (layout)?

Tags: android, android-layout, contextmenu, android-linearlayout, android-context

I have custom view that extends LinearLayout

```
public class IntelligentComponent extends LinearLayout implements OnCreateContextMenuListener{
```

I have overriden the onCreateContextMenu to create context menu, but I cannot find the
onConextItemSelected method to catch the selected item.

> The method onConextItemSelected(MenuItem) of type IntelligentComponent must override or implement a supertype method

What method should I use? Is there some sort of listener?

I create my menu like this:

```
    @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
      if (v != this) return;
      menu.add(Menu.NONE, ValueType.SPEED.ordinal(), 0 , ValueType.SPEED.name());
      menu.add(Menu.NONE, ValueType.HEARTRATE.ordinal(), 1 , ValueType.HEARTRATE.name());
      menu.add(Menu.NONE, ValueType.DISTANCE.ordinal(), 2 , ValueType.DISTANCE.name());
      //v.setO
}
```

Also I did not use the registerForContextMenu method, is that a problem? The menu gets displayed ok, but I cannot catch the item selected event. 
 Thanks for help.

Comment: Go through this : http://www.droidnova.com/how-to-create-an-option-menu,427.html

Comment: That is for activity, I need to do that in Layout or custom view. It's the line: @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) , that is my problem, I cannot override it, because it's not in view but in activity. Is there no way to create context menu and handle it from inside a view?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a silly answer but have you fixed the typo in the method name?

Comment: Yes, its not working like this either: @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
 {